# Webpage - Font size of table items on mobile phone browsers changes

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, web, font-size

I have this website, were I use tables extensively, in order to provide a lot of download files categorized.

http://files.is.tue.mpg.de/dtzionas/Hand-Object-Capture/
(you can see there the source html file, there is *no* css file)

Although on my desktop everything is rendered nicely (chrome, firefox) when I test things on my Android's 5 chrome (I didn't try yet with another browser), the font size of the table items behaves in a weird way.

If I keep refreshing the webpage, sometimes (1st image) the font size is consistent among all table items, but sometimes (2nd image) several items become bigger. I do not really know why this happens, so that I can look for a solution for this.

[image: nice result]

[image: weird result]

Comment: My theory is that since there is not style sheet on this page the browser is defaulting to it's base styles which is not consistent between platforms. On mobile Android will try to scale and zoom content it feels the user is going to interact with. It's a usability feature that usually can be overridden through CSS normalization. I would recommend adding a normalize stylesheet to your page and it will help iron out these inconsistencies. http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: This actually helped, I copied the css file of the link that you provide, and now everything looks like the 2nd image. The titles (left column) are smaller than the links corresponding to it (right column), but at least there is consistency, since earlier it could be that half of the links had small font size and half of them big. Now the bigger elements are the ones that the user can interact with, so I'm not sure if it is a bad idea or not.